# c++ string constant and static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++, c++11, static-initialization

I'm trying to understand when the static initialization order fiasco is a real problem. If I use a string constant like `kName` below would it suffer any of the problems of the static initialization order fiasco? Is this a problem in this case because an instance of `Derived` can be created before `kName` is initialized as in `main.cpp`?

```
// Base.cpp
namespace test {
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;

protected:
  explicit Base(const std::string &name);
};
} // namespace test

// Derived.cpp
namespace test {
static const std::string kName = "my name";

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base(kName) {}
  ~Derived() override = default;
};
} // namespace test

// main.cpp
int main() {
  test::Derived instance{};
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: static initialization order fiasco happens with depending static variable between several files.

Comment: So when would it be an actual problem using a string constant? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around when this can be a problem. If the instance of `test::Derived` were defined outside of `main()` would it be a problem?

Comment: Here you have only one (and so no dependencies). So you are fine. Having a static `Derived` in Base.cpp/main.cpp would be problematic.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37f28ee920b9f281) helps a bit to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` function will not be called until all "global" variables are initialized. That includes `static` member variables as well as variables in `namespace` scope (`static` or not).

So in this case it's no problem since you define the `instance` inside the `main` function.

It would be different if the definition of `instance` was done statically outside the `main` function.

Comment: Wow, ok. In my example I actually just defined the instance inside `main()` without any thought to give an example. So practically speaking it seems like using static string constants like this can be a bad thing to do since I don't know how people will instantiate the class. I see this kind of use often so I'm surprised.

Comment: @MikeSweeney SIOF normally only kicks in when more than one file is involved. The order of initialisations *within* a single translation unit is well-defined. The order across translatin units, not so much.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a hard time with this because with static objects having internal linkage my mind automatically thinks there can never be more than 1 translation unit involved.

Answer (score 2):

Within a specific translation unit, the order of initialization of static objects is guaranteed to be the order in which the object definitions appear in that translation unit. The order of destruction is guaranteed to be the reverse of the order of initialization.
*However, there is no guarantee concerning the order of initialization of static objects across translation units*. This is what is termed as static initialization order fiasco.

So here you will not have static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to contradict what "Some programmer dude" said.

Comment: How does it? He said "It would be different if the definition of `instance` was done **statically** outside the main function" But there is no such definition of `instance` outside the `main` function (i.e. in main.cpp).

Comment: Because what matters seems to be how/where `Derived` is instantiated and not how many static objects there are in the `Derived` class itself.

Comment: @MikeSweeney: I should have said, one static instance rather than one static variable. Anyway, I removed that sentence.